# stacked bar chart ordering dc.barChart

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a stacked bar chart and can't order the bars.
I get values on chart with below custom reduction .

```
agroup = areaDim.group().reduce(
         function (p, v) {
          ++p.number;
          p.A+= v.A;
          p.B+= v.B;
          p.C+= v.C;
          p.first= (p.A/p.B)*-100;
          p.second= (p.C/p.B)*-100;

          return p;
      },
      function (p, v) {
          --p.number;
          p.A-= v.A;
          p.B-= v.B;
          p.C-= v.C;            
          p.first= (p.A/p.B)*-100;
          p.second= (p.C/p.B)*-100;

          return p;
      },
      function () {
          return {number: 0, A: 0, B:0, C:0, first:0 ,second }
      });
```

My stacked bar chart code is below

```
                   exampChart
                        .dimension(areaDim)
                        .group(agroup,"a")
                        .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.first; })                            
                        .stack(agroup,"b", function(d) { 
                            return d.value.second; })
                        .width(2000)
                        .height(550)                          
                        .margins({top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 35, left: 40})
                        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function (d) { 
                            return d.areaDim; })))
                        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
                        .brushOn(false)
                        .elasticY(true)
                        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                        .legend(dc.legend().x(400).y(5).itemHeight(20).gap(5))                           
                        .yAxisPadding('10%')
```

I want to order bars in descending order of total value of first and second.

I tried adding :

```
.ordering(function(p) {return p.value.first+p.value.second})
```

It doesnt work.

Comment: `.ordering()` should work. Try removing `.domain(...)` from `d3.scale.ordinal()`? This also sets the order.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. It works.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for following up.

Comment: Now realized  when page first loads it works. But when i filter graph the order doesn't change according to new filter. It stays the same.  I rendered the table exampChart.render() . but doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding `.elasticX(true)` ?

Comment: Great ! just forgot to add it. Now it  renders x axis.